# Write depthMap buffer to file (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, metal, lidar

I work with the new iPadPro and a LIDAR app and am kinda new to SWIFT5 (normaly working on CordovaApps with minimal native coding needed)

I want to dump the CVPixelBuffer I get for a frame to a `.bin` file.

I get the buffer like this: `let depthMap = frame.sceneDepth!.depthMap`
It returns a `DepthFloat32` buffer.

After that I lock the address and fetch it:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(depthMap, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
var addr = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthMap)
```

How can I save these values to a file on my iPad? Would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it on my own. Here is my solution in case somebody needs it.

Gather all the necessary values:

```
let addr = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthMap)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthMap)
let bpr = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(depthMap)
```

Then I hand the bufferaddress to the Data obj to create a byte buffer in memory --> `Data`

```
let data = Data(bytes: addr!, count: (bpr*height))
do {
   let filename = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent(timestamp +"_depthbuffer.bin")
   try data.write(to: filename)
} catch {
   // do smth with errors
}
```

`getDirectory()` is a custom function to find the Documents Directory. I can get the created Files from the App Container.

Don't forgett to Lock & unlock the BufferAdress.